# Why the path to assets is added after path segment ? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, assets

When I added a path segment to my Ruby on Rails app `/pricing` the path to assets started to be added after it like this which causes 404:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/pricing/assets/bootstrap.min.css
```

This is the route:

```
get 'pricing/:level', :to => 'welcome2#pricing', as: "package_signup"
```

This is the controller:

```
class Welcome2Controller < ApplicationController
  def pricing
    @package_signup = params[:level] 
  end
end
```

This is the link on the index page linking to pricing/bronze:

```
<%= link_to 'package_signup bronze', package_signup_path('bronze') %><button class="btn btn-success">Get Started</button>
```

How can I keep the path to assets the same ? like this:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/bootstrap.min.css
```

This is where bootstrap is included:

```
<link href='assets/bootstrap.min.css' rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Show your code where `bootstrap.min.css` is included.

Comment: `pricing` isn't a sub domain, it is just a path segment. A subdomain would look like `pricing.localhost`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `/` (forward slash) before `assets`. It ensures that assets will be picked from root URL not from the current URL.

Like this:

```
<link href='/assets/bootstrap.min.css' rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: This is the right answer for a lot of applications. But if you ever need to have your application deployed in a subdirectory (e.g., the root of your application is at `https://somedomain.com/somepath/` instead of just `https://somedomain.com`), you'll need to adjust it. In that case, probably best to set [`relative_url_root`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#deploy-to-a-subdirectory-relative-url-root) and play around with [`stylesheet_link_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-stylesheet_link_tag).